# Login loading page

Tags: php, authentication, header, loading

I have a php site where a user has the ability to login. Once they submit the `POST` data with their credentials they are taken to a page that initiates a `session` and checks the `database`. This process takes a long time before the user is ultimately redirected to the backend of the site. Durring this time the user stairs at a blank white page. I would like to show some kind of loading page, but when anything printable is on the page I get a `header` error due to the redirect.

How can I create a loading page? I understand that ajax is an option but is it my only option?

**Update:**
The PHP application is mainly taking a long time because each login is dependent on a foreign **API** that needs to be **authorized** as well as **charging** data that needs to be queried. I am not trying to mask something I can easily fix, I am trying to create a better user interface.

The login process takes ~10 seconds.

Comment: sounds like you need to find out why it's taking so long to load instead of masking the problem.

Comment: Uhm how long is `long time`? And why wouldn't you make the time shorter by optimizing your scripts?

Comment: The check (with salting and all) shouldn't take that long. Use FireBug and see what's taking so long for the page to load.

Comment: I know why it is taking so long (in the question).

Comment: I'd go for Ajax. Seems less hackish and more clean to me to keep it all Javascript, and no iframes like in Eugens approach. Partially also because I just don't like iframes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easy way to handle this is as follows:

Once a user pressed loging, using javascript, hide the login button, inject some  [ajaxloader gif](http://ajaxload.info), than send an AJAX request with the login credentials, salt it properly, log the user in, post the response as JSON, and intercept that response, and in case of success - do redirect, incase of failure - print appropriate message.

some code:

login-handler.php

```
$user = new user();
if ($user -> login($_POST['uid'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['whatever']){
  $response['type'] = 'success';
}
else{
  $response['type'] = 'failure';
} 
echo json_encode($response);
```

js-login.js

```
$("#login").click(function(){
  // verify that user put user name, password and whatever, hide button and show ajax loader

  $.get("login-handler.php", {user: user, password: password}, function(data){
    if (data.type == "success"){
      window.location = "http://example.com/new/location/whatever";
    }
    else{
      //print message
    }
  }, "JSON"); 
});
```

EDIT: but I'd like to join the other folks and consider using a faster/different API, as 10 secs loading time is utterly ridiculous, unless it is for yourself, in which case - knock yourself out.

Answer (score 2):

There is a classic trick around this:

- Set the target of the login form to a (invisible) iframe, but in it just set a variable to a redirection URL
- On submit set the div carrying the username/password to .style.display='none', then set a already loaded "please wait" div to .style.display='block'
- When the iframe finally loads use document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.VarName to get the URL and write it to location.href